# Creating .xls file and On the Spot will be sent with C#

Tags: c#, email-attachments

Currently I just created a program which can send the .xls file, I used google smtp server so I can already sent email with that server in my program. And inside my program, based on my date, I can create  .xls file with today date and time. What I want to know is this file will be used to be attachment for the email. How I can do it?

Currently my file name is `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhss") + ".xls"` so I can create based on today date and time. How I can retrieve the file name to be used as email attachment?

Comment: Do you use .NET's SMTP client API and MailMessage objects?

Comment: Hi, Yes, I use .NET SMTP Client API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the .NET's default Emal api found in the `System.Net.Mail` namespace.

You can add the file as an [attachment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the [`System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.mailmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object.

The `System.Net.Mail.Attachment` class accepts a constructor that can take the stream which you could have used to create the xls file. So, if you create the excel file on the fly, you'll probably already have a reference to the stream where it is written. Then you need to use the code below:

```
using (Stream myXlsFileStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    // assumig you populate the stream like this...
    WriteXlsToStream(myXlsFileStream);
    myXlsFileStream.Flush();


    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    // configure mail message contents ...
    using (Attachment xlsAttachment = new Attachment(
            myXlsFileStream, 
            "FileNameToAppearInEmail.xls", 
            "application/xls"))
    {
        message.Attachments.Add(xlsAttachment);

        // send the message
    }
}
```

Please, note that the stream must not be closed, and all data should have been written to it. You may need to call `myXlsFileStream.Flush()` (as in above code) before adding the attachment, in order to ensure that the file is entirely written.

Comment: For this code, I already implemented about it. I have one question is I need to retrieve all the data from the database and export back to the excel file. And for the "FileNameToAppearInEmail.xls", 
       "application/xls" how I should retrieve back?

I already saved the .xls file with the generated time but I want to know when I can do it.

Comment: When you provide an attachment with a `Stream`, the saved file does not matter anymore. The attachment will read the stream and upload its contents to the messsage. The filename argument (`"FileNameToAppearInEmail.xls"`) is the name that will appear when someone receives the message. This will be the suggested name if the recipient wants to save the file.